# Finding mean of ascii values in a string MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, mean

The string I am given is as follows:

```
scrap1 = 
a le h
ke fd 
zyq  b
 ner i
```

You'll notice there are 2 blank spaces indicating a space (ASCII 32) in each row. I need to find the mean ASCII value in each column without taking into account the spaces (32). So first I would convert to with `double(scrap1)` but then how do I find the mean without taking into account the spaces?

Comment: Show your original input. The `scrap1` doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2):

If it's only the ASCII 32 you want to omit:

```
d = double(scrap1);
result = mean(d(d~=32)); %// logical indexing to remove unwanted value, then mean
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the intermediate spaces in the string with `scrap1(scrap1 == ' ') = '';` This replaces any space in the input with an empty string. Then you can do the conversion to double and average the result. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/158554) for other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you can use `regex` to find the space and ignore it. "\s"

`findSpace = regexp(scrap1, '\s', 'ignore')`

% I am not sure about the ignore case, this  what comes to my mind. but u can read more about regexp by typying  `doc regexp`.